# how to replace the spaces with ~ between specific position in every line of a file

Tags: unix, sed, text-processing

I have a requirement where the records in a file are "|" pipe delimited.
the field 4 to field 20 are of 20 characters each. These fields may have leading and trailing spaces or the entire field can be only spaces. I want to replace the space at the beginning and the end of pipe symbol for filed 4 to field 20 only.

How can i do it ?

SAMPLE record :

```
XXXX|XXXX| XXXXXX|05.00000% 02/01/2030|OXXXXXXX, TEST |XXXXXXW     |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |ORG |0001-01-01|10|14|XXX|2016-05-01|            |   |2016-10-14|0001-01-01|2030-02-01|2014-01-01|Y|2|000|1|I|            | | |N|SA          |N|2016-05-26|A|US|2016-05-01| |Y|N|08 |SDBM1       |Y|Y| |N| |N|N| |  |  | |  |R|            |            |N|            |            |0000000000000000.00|            |0000000000000000.0000|            |            |2|XXXXX|2014-10-06|AA   |2016-05-11|     |0001-01-01|     |0001-01-01|05.00000|2016-05-11|                                                                                                                                                      |C           |2010-09-10|0001-01-01|XXXX|     |2011-06-09|     |2011-06-09|2026-02-01|0000000100.000000000|P|          |0000000000.000000000|
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
....something.. |~  MAhesh   ~|~MAHESH  KMR|MKR   ~|.. till 20th field
```

Note the replace should happen only if it is a space in the beginning and end else it must not replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{for(i=4;i<=20;i++){$i = match($i,/^[[:space:]]/)? "~"substr($i,2): $i; $i = match($i,/[[:space:]]$/)? substr($i,1,19)"~":$i}} 1' < file
```

for readability

check if the filed has space at begin and end, then substitute accordingly

```
awk -F"|" '
BEGIN{OFS="|"}
{
 for(i=4;i<=20;i++){
    $i = match($i,/^[[:space:]]/) ? "~"substr($i,2): $i;
    $i = match($i,/[[:space:]]$/) ? substr($i,1,19)"~":$i
 }
} 1
' < file
```

Comment: Awesome . Works like a gem . Thank you this was the required solution.:)